# Unable to create log file on local or HDFS using log4j2 with jar while putting in spark submit command on yarn

Tags: linux, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I built a jar using maven and execute in spark submit command and I want to generate logs for jar in a separate file using log4j2 so putting log4j2.xml in resources folder in jar and also putting log4j2.xml in **--files** and **classpath** and I am giving the local path or HDFS path in log4j2.xml file but unable to generate log file on local or HDFS. 
I am running this using **YARN**

In Info logs of spark, it is written that local and destination are same for log4j2.xml.
After that no log file is being generated.

**log4j2.xml**

```
<appender name="R" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="file" value="/projects/example.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100KB"/>
    <!-- Keep one backup file -->
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="1"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p %t %c - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender>
```

Comment: did you check the **level** of log?

Comment: I have added ThresholdFilter also for logging only error logs. Actually I want to print only error logs of my jar file placed in spark submit command and for this, I am using log4j2 but not getting file generated at desired location. I am doing this on Yarn cluster.

Comment: Any luck on this?